# Overlapping in NodeJS/mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2, node-mysql, node-mysql2

When i joining 2 tables i have to get result as nested array how can i do it in nodejs with mysql2

if i am executing

```
SELECT users.id as user_id , users.name as user_name , comments.id  as comment_id , comments.comment as comment FROM users LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = 1
```

**I'm getting result as**

```
[{
"user_id" : 1,
"user_name" : "Naaban"
"comment_id" : "2",
"comment" : "Hello"
},
{
"user_id" : 1,
"user_name" : "Naaban"
"comment_id" : "3",
"comment" : "Bye"
}]
```

**My Expectation is**

```
{
"user_id" : 1,
"user_name" : "ramesh",
"comments" : [
{
"comment_id" : 2,
"comment" : "Hello"
},
{
"comment_id" : 3,
"comment" : "Bye"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do that directly from the query however you can normalize your code as follows:

```js
let data = [{
  user_id : 1,
  user_name : "Naaban",
  comment_id : "2",
  comment : "Hello"
  },
  {
  user_id : 1,
  user_name : "Naaban",
  comment_id : "3",
  comment : "Bye"
  }];
  
  let normalizedData = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    const comment = {comment_id: data[i].comment_id, comment: data[i].comment};
    const { user_id, user_name} = data[i];
    normalizedData.push({ user_id, user_name, comment });
  }
  console.log(normalizedData);
```

Comment: Bro i need query result, what i am expecting? But you rendered result in forloop i don't wan't to do it in a for loop...